# ServiceStack service separation from business logic

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have a question on how to properly approach the separation of a Web API service from the business logic particularly when using service stack. The code that I am trying to improve on is similar to the following:

```
public class TenantService : Service
{
   public object Post(TenantRequest req)
   {
       //create an instance of the struct to hold the data
       TenantObject tenant = new tenant{ //set properties from the resquest};
       TenantRecord.InsertRecord(tenant)
       // create a response after this //
   }  
}
```

then in my business logic I have something similar to the following:

```
public class TenantRecord
{
    public static void InsertRecord(TenantObject tenant)
    {
         //Instantiate a new Tenant POCO
         Tenant newRecord = new Tenant
         {
         Id = 1, Name = tenant.Name, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, ...//And so on
         };
         db.Insert(newRecord);
     }
  }
```

This is causing a massive headache dealing with constantly re-writing the same code mostly mapping code, but the constant creation of structs to transfer the information back and forth causes a ton of data mapping. Also, in some cases, one request has to handle a lot of different types of information.

Should the business logic reference the API and pass the request itself, or is this current method the most appropriate approach? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could try using the [ServiceStack AutoMapper](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-mapping)(created for such situations).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ServiceStack provides AutoMapping extension methods](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-mapping) that make mapping to DTO object to your model straightforward so you shouldn't have to manually setup the relationships.

So your `Insert` method simply becomes:

```cs
public class TenantService : Service
{
    public object Post(TenantRequest req)
    {
        var tenant = new Tenant { CreatedDate = DateTime.Now }.PopulateWith(req);
        Db.Save(tenant);
        return new { Id = tenant.Id };
    }
}
```

I would keep the business logic in the action methods, unless you have a specific need for this additional abstraction, such as reusability. *Besides your static `InsertRecord` method would require to resolve an instance of the `db`. Adding unnecessary complication.*

Comment: I did need the further seperation, but this answer fit the needs for the project perfectly.